# Apache Flex SDK 4.15 - how to install?

Tags: apache, flash, apache-flex, air, mxml

I try install 4.15 SDK by Apache Flex SDK Installer and get this error

```
Fetched the SDK download mirror URL from the CGI.
Error #2048
Installation aborted
Error #2002

Installation aborted
```

If i downloaded sources from http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html and http://flex.apache.org/download-binaries.html and try use one of this or its files mix my Flash Builder 4.7 always gives a variety of errors and does not define the SDK.

Comment: Did you make sure to download "AIR 24 SDK for Flex Developers", and not the "AIR 24 SDK & Compiler Beta" ?

Comment: Sometimes the Flex installer fails, this mostly happens when one of the servers is down. Try downloading it again but select Adobe AIR 23 or Adobe AIR 22.